# How to maintain the custom methods while using generated classes using RIA services and entity models?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

How to maintain the custom methods while using generated classes using RIA services and entity models ?

Everytime the model changes, the only way to generate methods for these entities is to regenerate the DomainService class. But if we do that, the custom methods that we have created in the DomainService class gets overwritten. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `partial` keyword for `YourDomainService` class and define another class for writing your own code. By regenerating the `YourDomainService` class, you can save your codes!